# Is it possible to stop undeploying web app while shutting dow wildfly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I'm new to JEE and i'd like to know if it is possible to not undeploy EAR project when shutting down wildfly. I've a web App running on wildfly 16.0.0.Final which is installed as a service on windows server 2012R2. So wildfly deploy my app at every start up of windows and it can take some time.

So here is my concern, is it possible to keep my app deployed on wildfly even if i shutdow windows?

Answer (score 1):

During the shutdown of WildFly will always undeploy the application as resources need to ensure they've been shutdown. By default WildFly also does this gracefully.

The same goes with the startup. The applications will always need to go through the deployment process to ensure all the resources are available.

For the startup time you could look at why it's taking so long to start WildFly. Is the application very large? If so can it be broken into smaller pieces?

Another possible option might be to have the service automatically start. I'm not a Windows expert, but I think there is a way to do a delayed auto-start.